# asp.net core 2.0 publish to azure get IIS 502.5 Error

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am starting with asp.net core 2.0
Created a new project with VS 2017. Published it to the windows azure. I got the error IIS 502.5
[image]

Check the log stream, I see this

> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: The short switch '-argFile' is not defined in the switch mappings.
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.CommandLineConfigurationProvider.Load()
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
>      at RecruitmentStore.Host.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args) in D:\RecruitmentStore\RecruitmentStore.Host\Program.cs:line 20
>      at RecruitmentStore.Host.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\RecruitmentStore\RecruitmentStore.Host\Program.cs:line 17
>
> IIS Detailed
>   Error - 502.5 - Bad Gateway

And here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00" 
                processPath="bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" 
                arguments="-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt" 
                forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" 
                stdoutLogEnabled="true" 
                stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I see the file IISExeLauncherArgs.txt generated inside the bin folder (in my local), but have no idea how it works in Azure.

[image]

Can you please tell me how to fix this? I did restarted the app service several times, that doesn't help

Comment: Please post the output as **text** and not a screenshot of the text. This makes it easier for everyone :)

Comment: okay, I edited my question, thanks

Comment: And this is with an unmodified default Core 2.0 app created by VS? The web.config does not normally have all these extra switches, so there is something unusual about how you deploy it.

Comment: yes, this is the default one created by the VS 2017, ASP.net Core SDK 2.0. What is unusual part?

Comment: A default app does not have a web.config at all, and one gets generated during build (should look like [this](https://github.com/davidebbo-test/AspNetCore20)). So probably something strange with the way you created it if you have that in your project.

Comment: yes, you are right, I am hosting the asp.net core 2.0 in the IIS, it is working just fine with IIS, the web.config is auto added by the IIS. But is that the problem?

Comment: But if you deploy from VS to App Service, you should not be getting a config like that. I'm pretty sure that's why it's broken.

Comment: How exactly are you publishing to your Azure Web App? You need to right click on the project and choose Publish, and it should do the right thing. The web.config you show here is used for local debugging in VS, and should never end up on App Service.

Comment: yes, right click and publish, new an Azure profile

Comment: Puzzling. I will ask the VS and Core experts (I'm more on the Azure side).

Comment: One more thing: go to Extension and Updates and make sure you have the latest everything, in case it's some old bug that's fixed. e.g. latest VS is 15.3.5.

Comment: oops, you are right @DavidEbbo, it works okay when I get the web.config excluded from the project, thank you.

Comment: @DavidEbbo can you post the answer, so that I can mark it "answered"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155983/discussion-between-khoailang-and-david-ebbo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we found, the problem is that you have as part of your project a `web.config` that is only meant to be used when debugging locally in Visual Studio. If you exclude it form the project, msbuild will generate the correct one at deployment time, and it will run correctly on Azure.

Comment: @DavidvanDugteren yes, after talking to VS expert, his conclusion is that the real cause might be a VS publishing issue, which is why he filed this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/242).

Comment: Do you know how to pulsing core 2.0 to aws?

Answer (score 4):

web.config has `arguments="-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt"` attribute that needs to be removed during publish. Here's a sample ASP.NET Core 2.0 app where this is achieved during publish. I tested this with "File System" and "Web Deploy Package" options (useful for AWS EB deployments)

https://github.com/clearwaterstream/aspnet-websdk-issue242-workaround

Comment: Shame this needs gulp to be installed to work. Surely you can replace a string in a file on Windows without Node and Gulp??

Comment: there are solutions using powershell w/o using gulp,
 see https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/242  

also, this SDK already has the issue fixed: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.300-preview1